# How to insert image figure numbers in list of figures section under the table of contents

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents

I have couple of images in every chapter and I need to specify a figure number for every image depending on the chapter and it must get automatically reflected in the list of figures section. How do I achieve this? Please help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Usually, this is something that is done automatically with `\listoffigures`, depending on the class however. Please provide a minimal working document with `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}...\end{document}`

Comment: Use `\begin{figure}...\caption{figure description}\end{figure}` and `\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}` (requires `chngcntr` package), if the `figure` counter isn't in the chapter counter reset list (but this is a standard, actually, at least for `book` class)

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{book}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures


\chapter{First}

\begin{figure}
\caption{First figure from chapter \thechapter}

\caption{Second figure from chapter \thechapter}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Second Chapter}

\begin{figure}
\caption{First figure from chapter \thechapter}

\caption{Second figure from chapter \thechapter}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks a ton for the response. But I have some clarification in my code. Please help

`\chapter{chap1}
\section{chap1section1}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{img1.png}
\caption{cap1}
\end{figure}`

and couple of other images too...

`\section{chap1sec2}`

But when I compile the code only the first image is placed under the section 1 as it is of figure 1.1 and all other images are placed after section 2 because they have captions 1.2,... and so on. All I did was include the images under section1. Kindly help...

Comment: @Guru: That's the floating mechanism of LaTeX, this has nothing to do with your first question. If you don't floating figures, use `\includegraphics{...} \captionof{figure}{cap1}` etc. You need the `caption` package then